# program fails to run with GCC but works with clang

Tags: c, gcc, clang

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct tmp_num{
    int tmp_1;
    int tmp_2;
}t_num;

/* Dichiarazione prototipi secondo le direttive di pthread */
void *num_mezzo_1(void *num_orig);
void *num_mezzo_2(void *num_orig);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    /* Inizializzo i 2 thread */
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int tmp=0,rc1,rc2,num;

    t_num main_tnum;
    num=atoi(argv[1]);
    if(num <= 3){
        printf("Questo è un numero primo: %d\n", num);
        exit(0);
    }
    if( (rc1=pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &num_mezzo_1, (void *)num)) ){
        printf("Creazione del thread fallita: %d\n", rc1);
        exit(1);
    }
    if( (rc2=pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &num_mezzo_2, (void *)num)) ){
            printf("Creazione del thread fallita: %d\n", rc2);
            exit(1);
    }
    main_tnum.tmp_1 = 0;
    main_tnum.tmp_2 = 0;
    pthread_join(thread1, (void **)&(main_tnum.tmp_1));
    pthread_join(thread2, (void **)&(main_tnum.tmp_2));
    tmp=main_tnum.tmp_1+main_tnum.tmp_2;
    if(tmp>2){
        printf("Questo NON è un numero primo: %d\n", num);
    }
    else{
        printf("Questo è un numero primo: %d\n", num);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void *num_mezzo_1(void *num_orig){
    t_num p1_tnum;
    int cont_1;
    int n_orig=(int)num_orig;
    p1_tnum.tmp_1 = 0;
    for(cont_1=1; cont_1<=(n_orig/2); cont_1++){
        if((n_orig % cont_1) == 0){
            (p1_tnum.tmp_1)++;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)(p1_tnum.tmp_1));
    return NULL;
}

void *num_mezzo_2(void *num_orig){
    t_num p2_tnum;
    int cont_2;
    int n_orig=(int)num_orig;
    p2_tnum.tmp_2 = 0;
    for(cont_2=((n_orig/2)+1); cont_2<=n_orig; cont_2++){
        if((n_orig % cont_2) == 0){
            (p2_tnum.tmp_2)++;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit((void *)(p2_tnum.tmp_2));
    return NULL;
}
```

I'm using Debian Sid 64bit and i have a problem with this simple program that i have developed.
If i compile with `clang -Wall -Wextra -o test prime.c -lpthread` i got only 1 warn (*unused argc*) and the program runs fine.
But if i compile it with GCC-4.7.2 (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -o test prime.c -lpthread`) i got **more** warns (*unused argc* + various *cast from pointer to integer of different size*) and the program fails with a SegFault.
I don't understand why with clang it works and with GCC it doesn't.

**EDIT:**

```
num_primo_pthread.c: In function ‘main’:
num_primo_pthread.c:33:57: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
num_primo_pthread.c:37:57: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
num_primo_pthread.c:16:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
num_primo_pthread.c: In function ‘num_mezzo_1’:
num_primo_pthread.c:61:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
num_primo_pthread.c:68:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
num_primo_pthread.c: In function ‘num_mezzo_2’:
num_primo_pthread.c:75:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
num_primo_pthread.c:82:15: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Comment: Post your warnings.  It's probably because clang is fixing some easy mistake, but gcc is giving you all the thread you need to hang yourself by.

Comment: Also:  It's good practice to always eliminate warnings.  They're there to let you know about possibly dangerous situations.  They generally will still compile because the best and most experienced programmers can sometimes bend the language in ways a compiler can't see, but 90+% of the time, you should eliminate them.  You'll thank yourself in the long run.

I had a professor in college who would mark off points if your code compiled with warns.  Sometimes, I wish all professors did that.

Comment: Generally spoken, don't use casts if you don't understand what they are doing. Here in addition you have the compiler telling you exactly what is wrong, so fix that instead of just shooting you in the foot. The fact that clang doesn't detect this basic error is astonishing. I am not sure that your are compiling for exactly the same architecture.

Comment: With gcc 4.7.1 on Debian Wheezy 64bit, it works

Comment: @OttavioCampana O.o oh dear! It is incredible :O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem lies in this line

```
int n_orig=(int)num_orig;
```

num_orig is a pointer to an int, not an int. replace with:

```
int n_orig=(int)*num_orig;
```

Edit:

The problem lies a little bit deeper:

```
(void *)num
```

you can't do that, pointers are not used that way, change it to

```
(void *)&num
```

Second edit after viewing the errors:

You are doing the same with the return function

```
(void *)(p2_tnum.tmp_2)
```

needs to be

```
(void *)(&p2_tnum.tmp_2)
```

And this is a local variable so you can't return it.

```
t_num p2_tnum
```

Has to be a pointer with dynamic memory allocated.

```
t_num *p2_tnum = (t_num *) malloc(sizeof(t_num));
```

These fixes will require you to do some additional modifications, but I think you can manage those.

Comment: No; if you look, `num_orig` isn't actually a pointer, it's an `int` casted to a `void *` as that's the interface of `pthread_create`.

Comment: never saw someone do that :x, still, I think the problem lies there

Comment: if i do what you say 1) the program becomes very slow 2) with GCC it still doesn't work :(

Comment: In your second edit, `(void *)(p2_tnum.tmp_2)` is, horribile dictu, exactly what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: @polslinux The programme is very slow because it's a terrible algorithm it uses.

Comment: @DanielFischer yea :x very weird that clang allows these things, then again, it isn't very mature yet

Comment: The problem lies in the use of casts. They are just hiding problems instead of solving them. The most dangerous of them is `(void*)`.

Comment: The clang is probably a 32 bit version where `int` and `void*` are both 32 bit.

Comment: @JensGustedt I don't even know if that matters, he can just as well cast a 32bit int to a 64bit address and think he is doing hot stuff.

Comment: @Minion91 It would explain why clang doesn't warn about the different sizes of origin and target of the cast.

Comment: @DanielFischer That is probably true. I don't work with clang so I don't really know what warnings it gives and what kind of weird stuff you can do with it. But apparently casting ints to void pointers is totally acceptable. Ah, how i love random weirdness.

Comment: Well, the standard allows casts between integer types and pointer types, but the behaviour is implementation-defined (with a few exceptions, an integer constant with value 0 must yield a null pointer). You're not guaranteed to round-trip, and `pointer-> integer` may invoke undefined behaviour.